# Automatically import a macro to Excel and run it

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, vba

I have made a module i.e. a `.bas` file which does the work I want to do in Excel. I have to work with this same module in four different files everyday.

Now I want, let's say, a script which automatically link this module with the Excel file and then the macro executes all by itself.

The piece of code that I have tried till now is:

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Denied_report.csv", 0, True) 
  xlApp.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!AllowedMacro"
  xlApp.SaveAs
  xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

I am using Personal file so that it is available to all Excel files and doesn't have to import it everytime by opening the Excel file and doing so!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the Workbook_open function. This will run as soon as you open Excel.

```
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'runs once per Excel session when Personal.xlsb is opened.
    Set App = Application
    MsgBox "Running Workbook_Open from Personal.xlsb"
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "Running App_WorkbookOpen in " & Wb.Name
    'add code you want to run upon opening each workbook here
   '.....
End Sub
```

See: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/562394-workbook_open-personal-xlsb-problems-need-correct-sub-procedure.html

Comment: @Robert Ilbrink The above one is answer of my question. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this instead and this worked:

```
Option Explicit

    LaunchMacro

  Sub LaunchMacro() 
      Dim xl
      Dim xlBook      
      Dim strFile


        strFile = "C:\De1.csv"
        Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
        Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\De.csv", 0, False ) 

        xl.Application.Visible = True

        xl.Application.run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Allowed_Macro"
        xl.DisplayAlerts = False        
        xlBook.saved = True
        xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFile

        xl.activewindow.close
        xl.Quit

        Set xlBook = Nothing
        Set xl = Nothing

End Sub
```

The only problem I am facing now is that I am whatever formatting my macro does, they don't persist after saving.

Comment: Please open as a new question - ideally on StackOverflow!

Comment: .CSV does not store any formatting, only the data! You need to save it as .xlsm!

Comment: @PeterAlbert Questions about Excel macros can also be asked here, they're not off topic.

Comment: @slhck: Ok, good to know. Though I guess just from looking at the audience, SO will most likely have more VBA experts look at it...

Comment: @PeterAlbert I tried renaming it to .xlsm while saving but then that .xlsm file throws an error and doesn't open. Any tricks?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in comment guys, was ill from past 2 days :/

Comment: @DeveloperbyBlood: Try `xlBook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` or `xlBook.SaveAs FileFomat:=52`